# Displaying a dynamic number of controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a problem writing sensible logic when displaying a dynamic number of controls, which could range from any number from 1 to 9. So, if user input is 1, the control should attempt to fill the screen, if the user input is 2 the two controls should split the screen evenly, if the number is 3 one control would display on the top 50% of the screen while two controls should split the bottom 50% of the screen etc.

The solution I've come up with till now involves making a ton of grid rows and columns in the code behind that, depending on user input, assigns the controls to the right rows and columns. However, this solution feels like a hack and results in lots of unnecessary code. It's also not at all flexible if I want to expand the number of controls later.

I have a feeling there has to be an easier way to approach this problem, any suggestions?

Comment: You could use an `ItemsControl` and a `WrapPanel` as `ItemsPanelTemplate` to achive this. You just have to define the template for the items and the `ItemsControl` will show them.

Comment: First problem here is to associate user input with layout, e.g. number `3` layout is not similar in any way to `1` or `2` unless you continue and there is a rule.

Comment: maybe the ```UniformGrid``` helps. If you set the rows to something like ```Rows=(int)sqrt(Number)```.

Comment: @Sinatr That is precisely the problem, yes.

Comment: @Iqon Hmm that might work, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You can also write your own logic how to arrange the controls with a custom layout panel using `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` (https://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html)

Comment: @Iqon the UniformGrid won't give the desired behaviour as all the controls will be the same size. This https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/uniformgrid/ is a nice tutorial on it.

Comment: Yes, if there are odd numbers it won't fit the requirements (this is why I posted the suggestion only in the comments). But I had a similar case in a project of mine. In the end, we used the uniform grid.

Comment: As @Sinatr mentioned, you have to define the exact rules how you want to arrange your views. How does it look like with `4` or `7`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend `Grid` or a similar control and override it's layout behavior for your custom logic, while not having to re-invent the wheel.

For example, you can create a dynamic-grid control in following manner (it works with any number of children and automatically adjusts the number of rows and columns):

```
public class DynamicGrid : Grid
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AdjustColumnWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AdjustColumnWidth",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(DynamicGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange));
    public static double GetAdjustColumnWidth(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (double)d.GetValue(AdjustColumnWidthProperty);
    }
    public static void SetAdjustColumnWidth(DependencyObject d, double value)
    {
        d.SetValue(AdjustColumnWidthProperty, value);
    }

    private int getSquareLength(int items)
    {
        double result = Math.Sqrt(items);
        return (int)Math.Ceiling(result);
    }

    private int getColumns(int length)
    {
        return length;
    }

    private int getRows(int length)
    {
        var count = _currentChildrenCount;

        //assume we can have empty row
        var rows = length - 1;

        //if fits the bill - great!
        if (rows * length >= count)
            return rows;
        else
            return rows + 1;
    }

    private int _currentChildrenCount;
    private void OnNumberOfItemsChangedImpl()
    {
        var numOfChildren = _currentChildrenCount;

        using (var d = Dispatcher.DisableProcessing())
        {
            RowDefinitions.Clear();
            ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

            if (numOfChildren > 0)
            {
                var squareLength = getSquareLength(numOfChildren);

                var numOfCols = getColumns(squareLength);
                var numOfRows = getRows(squareLength);

                for (var i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++)
                    RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                for (var i = 0; i < numOfCols; i++)
                    ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

                var adjustWidthFactor = 1.0;
                var adjustWidthOnLastRow = numOfChildren < (numOfCols * numOfRows);
                if (adjustWidthOnLastRow)
                {
                    var notEmptySlots = (numOfChildren % numOfCols);
                    adjustWidthFactor = ((double)numOfCols / (double)notEmptySlots);
                }

                int row = 0, col = 0;
                foreach (var view in Children)
                {
                    var cell = (FrameworkElement)view;

                    SetRow(cell, row);
                    SetColumn(cell, col);

                    if (adjustWidthOnLastRow && row == (numOfRows - 1))
                        SetAdjustColumnWidth(cell, adjustWidthFactor);
                    else
                        SetAdjustColumnWidth(cell, 1.0);

                    if (++col >= numOfCols)
                    {
                        col = 0;
                        row++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        var toReturn = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);

        foreach (var view in Children)
        {
            var cell = (FrameworkElement)view;
            var adjustWidthFactor = GetAdjustColumnWidth(cell);

            var bounds = LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot(cell);
            var newBounds = new Rect(
                    x: bounds.Width * adjustWidthFactor * GetColumn(cell),
                    y: bounds.Top,
                    width: bounds.Width * adjustWidthFactor,
                    height: bounds.Height
                );

            cell.Arrange(newBounds);
        }

        return toReturn;
    }

    public DynamicGrid()
    {
        _currentChildrenCount = 0;

        LayoutUpdated += (s, e) => {
            if (Children?.Count != _currentChildrenCount)
            {
                _currentChildrenCount = (Children != null) ? Children.Count : 0;
                OnNumberOfItemsChangedImpl();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

### Sample usage 1: - Static collection

```
<local:DynamicGrid Margin="20">
    <Button>one</Button>
    <Button>two</Button>
    <Button>three</Button>
    <Button>four</Button>
    <Button>five</Button>
    <Button>six</Button>
    <Button>seven</Button>
    <Button>eight</Button>
</local:DynamicGrid>
```

[image]

### Sample usage 2: - With ItemsControl

```
<ItemsControl Margin="20">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:DynamicGrid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Gray" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <col:ArrayList>
            <sys:String>one</sys:String>
            <sys:String>two</sys:String>
            <sys:String>three</sys:String>
            <sys:String>four</sys:String>
            <sys:String>five</sys:String>
        </col:ArrayList>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
</ItemsControl>
```

[image]

### Sample usage 3: - Dynamic collection

```
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="slider">
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <local:CountToCollectionConverter />
                </Binding.Converter>
            </Binding>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="Gray" Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <local:DynamicGrid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

    <Slider x:Name="slider"
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Minimum="1" 
            Maximum="12" 
            TickFrequency="1" 
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

### How it works

Whenever the children collection on the `Grid` is updated, it tries to find the nearest perfect square to the children-count. Once found, it calculates the number of columns and rows based on computed square-length; and defines the `RowDefinitions`, and `ColumnDefinitions` accordingly. If there is space left in last row, it adjusts the width of controls to fill the space.

---

*Please note: As no specific rules have been specified in the question, I have customized this grid to just adjust the items in last row*

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for you in-depth explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `StackPanel` for each row and one for your "grid" like this

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel/>
    <StackPanel/>
</StackPanel>
```

You could then add and fill your rows as required to match the layout for your given configuration - e.g. for 3 controls - 2 in row 1 and 1 in row 2, for 4 controls - 2 in row 1 and 2 in row 2, etc...

You could then bind the widths of the controls in each row to a property that was a function of how many controls there were in that particular row. For example, if there were 3 in a row each control would be 1/3 of the width. As long as you update this width property whenever you modify a row the control widths will be updated to fill your available space.

To add additional layouts you simply need to add new rules to your layout configuration.